# What is the type of discontinuity of $\frac{\exp x-1}{\exp|x|-1}$ at $0$? Is it piecewise continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{e^x -1}{e^{|x|}-1} & \text{if $x \ne 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x = 0$}\end{cases}$.

What is the type of discontinuity at $0$? Is $f$ piecewise continuous?

I know there are three types removable, jump, and essential. 
and a piecewise continuous has only finite number of discontinuities on every bounded subinterval of its domain and they must be removable or jump.

How do i find the lim f(x) as it aproaches 0? and see if it equals f(0) to check if its removable.

Also how to find the one sided limits as it approaches 0 and see if they dont equal to check if its a jump

Plus, is this the only discontinuity. if it is then it must be piecewise continuous.

Comment: It is so [easy to cheat](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4psv3cr1pm), nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>0$, then $f(x)\equiv1$, but 
$$\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{e^x-1}{e^{-x}-1}=-1,$$ hence $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=$ does not exist, and $f(0)=0$. $f$ is piecewise continuous (on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$).

Comment: isnt the left sided limit equal to -1?? this proves its a jump

Comment: @josh: If $f(x)=g(x)/h(x)$, where $g$, $h$ are continuous, than it is continuous if only $h(x_0)\neq0$.

Comment: thanks best answer, i am going to put another discontinuity question in a few min, please check it out

Comment: @josh: You are right. Corrected.